# Will Windows phone still receive notifications once app is un-installed

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

If an app registers for Push notifications on a Windows Phone 8. Later if the user un-installs the app will he/she still continue to receive notifications for the same app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the app is uninstalled, it also unregisters with the push notification server. If you push ( in error ) a notification for an uninstalled app, you will get a corresponding error.